# ImportError: cannot import name 'RelationshipPath' from 'featuretools.entityset.relationship'

Tags: python, import, importerror

I'm attempting to just import featuretools but I get this error.

```
from featuretools import entityset

ImportError: cannot import name 'RelationshipPath' from 'featuretools.entityset.relationship'
```

I haven't had much luck finding a solution to this or any mention of this after a number of google searches.

I have reviewed the documentation on https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/generated/featuretools.EntitySet.html#featuretools.EntitySet but cannot find what's going on exactly. I'm a few months into learning python so this is probably over my head.

Comment: What is your `featuretools` version?

Comment: featuretools version 1.28.0

Comment: and what python version?

Comment: I am using Python 3.10.13 and anaconda as my pkg manager.